# RUBY: Search and Find in text file, remove blocks of text

Tags: regex, ruby, search, text

I am currently struggling on a project for work. In a nutshell, we have a big, 3 million line long (so not editable by hand) text file automatically generated by a piece of software. This text file describes variables, that are formated as such:

```
/begin var_type var_name
[content of variable]
/end var_type
```

However, because of some mess up along the production line, some variables are duplicated, which bothers the end user. This is what we have:

```
/begin var_type var_name              //the original variable
[content of variable]
/end var_type
```

and a bit later, we have

```
/begin var_type var_name_ext          //same type, same name but with "_ext" at the end
[same content of variable]
/end var_type
```

I'm not that great of a dev, but i figured the algorithm should:

```
1: search for every name of variables_ext
2: check if they indeed have a "non _ext" counterpart"
         -> if not (there is a var_name_ext but no non _ext counterpart), leave them alone
         -> if yes, the algorithm does what the client wants, i.e:
                        a: delete original variable block (from /begin to /end)
                        b: delete "_ext" name extension in the name of the var_name_ext variable
```

The part where I'm stuck is that, for integration purposes, this needs to be done in Ruby, a language I am familiar in but am not really that proficient with, as I am a beginner. I figured i need to use regular expressions, but I can't really grasp the way to implement it in my case.
I managed to do basic searches that print "true" to the console output when it sees a /begin or a /end tag, but I'm really stuck on the implementation of the algorithm.

Any help/suggestions is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have to do two passes, the first to search for the "ext" definitions, and the second to remove the overridden values.

You can proceed like this

```
require 'set'

f = File.open(filename)
vars = Set.new(f.each_line.grep(/^\/begin /)) { |line| line.split.last }

overridden = vars.select do |var|
  vars.include?("#{var}_ext") && vars.include?(var)
end

overridden = Set.new(overridden)
to_rename = Set.new(overridden) { |var| "#{var}_ext" }

f.close
```

now you have all the overridden variables, you can reopen the file and do your transformation

```
f = File.open(filename)

out = File.open(output_filename, 'w')

skipping = false # use it to skip block of lines

f.each_line do |line|
  next if skipping

  if line.start_with?('/begin ') && overridden.include?(line.split.last)
    skipping = true
  elsif line.start_with?('/end ') && overridden.include?(line.split.last)
    skipping = false
  elsif line.start_with?('/begin ') && to_replace.include?(line.split.last)
    out << line.gsub(/_ext\n/, "\n")
  elsif line.start_with?('/end ') && to_replace.include?(line.split.last)
    out << line.gsub(/_ext\n/, "\n")
  else
    out << line
  end
end

out.close
f.close
```

Basically you write out in a new file, provided you are not in an overridden block, where you use a flag to prevent writing.

Comment: Thank you, amended :) I was coming from answering at math.stackexchange so my fingers were in "LaTeX" mode 

Comment: About closing, if this is an isolated script the files will be garbage collected, and there are only 3 file descriptors used. I see the point of generally closing opened files though, but I didn't want to complicate too much the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's create an example for demonstration purposes.

```
File.write('in', <<~END
/begin d1 collie
collie woof
/end d1
/begin d2 pug
pug woof
/end d2
/begin d3 beagle
beagle woof
beagle woof-woof
/end d3
/begin d1 collie_ext
collie woof
/end d1
/begin d4 poodle_ext
poodle woof
/end d4
END
)
  #=> 204
```

---

Now let's read the file for the purpose of creating a hash that specifies how the file should be modified.

```
remove_ext =
  File.foreach('in', chomp: true).with_object({}) do |line,remove_ext|
    next unless line.start_with?('/begin ')
    key = line[7..-1]
    if key[-4..-1] == '_ext'
      base = key[0..-5]
      if remove_ext.key?(base)
        remove_ext.delete(base)
        remove_ext[key] = true
      else
        remove_ext[key] = false
      end
    else
      remove_ext[key] = false
    end
  end
    #=> {"d2 pug"=>false, "d3 beagle"=>false,
    #    "d1 collie_ext"=>true, "d4 poodle_ext"=>false}
```

We may now create the desired file.

```
File.open('out', 'w') do |fout|
  write_lines = true
  File.foreach('in', chomp: true) do |line|
    if line.start_with?('/begin ')
      key = line[7..-1]
      if remove_ext.key?(key)
        write_lines = true
        line = line[0..-5] if remove_ext[key]
      else
        write_lines = false
      end
    end
    fout.puts(line) if write_lines
  end
end
```

Let's see what was written.

```
puts File.read('out')
/begin d2 pug
pug woof
/end d2
/begin d3 beagle
beagle woof
beagle woof-woof
/end d3
/begin d1 collie
collie woof
/end d1
/begin d4 poodle_ext
poodle woof
/end d4
```

---

An alternative approach with lower memory requirements could be taken if there is a known integer `N` such that if the "non-ext" block is the `i`th block and the corresponding "ext" entry, if there is one, is the `j`th block, `i < j`, then `j - i <= N`. In other words, "a bit later" means "within `N` blocks".

In this case to determine if a block were to be written to the new file, with or without an "ext" extension, one would examine a continually-updated hash that caches the "next" `N` blocks (or all remaining blocks in the file if there are fewer than `N`).

---

Addendum: to remove the extra newlines mentioned in a comment try the following.

```
File.write('bad', <<~END
/begin d1 collie
collie woof
/end d1
/begin d2

 pug
pug woof
/end d2
/begin d3 


beagle
beagle woof
beagle woof-woof
/end d3
END
)
```

```
puts File.read('good')
/begin d1 collie
collie woof
/end d1
/begin d2 pug
pug woof
/end d2
/begin d3 beagle
beagle woof
beagle woof-woof
/end d3
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the very complete answer, I have just a tiny thing that's not clear:

Could you explain the key[-4..-1] == '_ext' syntax? is it because we want to "extract" the last 3 characters, so from -1 to -4? would it be [-(n+1)..-1] if we wanted to remove an n-long suffix?

Comment: UPDATE: just implemented your vesion, works great! I was heading towards a dictionary approach, where I would have a file with the _ext variable names in it, but yours seems more straightforwards. However, there is an issue i forgot to adress. It seems the formating is not consistent, i.e sometimes, there might be a carriage return/line feed or two between the variable type and the variable name... How would you adapt in this situation?

Comment: To remove an n-long suffix from `str`, `str[-n..-1] = ''` or `str = str[0..-(N+1)]`. Regarding the unwanted characters between the variable type and name, I would be inclined to remove the unwanted characters as an initial step. If you'd like code for that let me know.

Comment: thanks for the clear up! the piece of code for the unwanted characters would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please be more specific about the problem with the newlines. Which of the following may occur: `'/begin d1\r\n pug'`, `'/begin d1 \r\npug'` `'/begin d1\r\npug'`, `'/begin d1\r\n\r\n pug'`, `'/begin d1 \r\n\r\npug'`, `'/begin d1\r\n \r\npug'` , `'/begin d1\r\n\r\npug'`, all of the foregoing with `\n` substituted for `\r\n` and all of the foregoing with `'/end'` substituted for `'/begin'`? Get in the habit of being precise when specifying code requirements.

Comment: I think I abused the term, sorry, by carriage return i just mean that when opened in a text editor there is an "empty line" or 2 between the /begin d1 and the varname, so for instance, /begin d1 is on line 1, and varname is sometimes on line 2, or 3.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, indeed that is how the file is formated. How would you remove these lines extra lines?

Comment: I added code to correct the file contents. I intended to include that code in of my previous revision, to follow the creation of the file `'bad'`, but somehow it didn't make it into print.

Answer (score -1):

Push each and every text variable in to an **Associative hash array**, it will remove the duplicate variable content. No need to do any function.

Try this method, it will help you out.

Below is the sample syntax, it will ignore the last "TextContent2":

```
harray = Hash.new
harray["TextContent1"] = '1' 
harray["TextContent2"] = '1' 
harray["TextContent3"] = '1'
harray["TextContent2"] = '1'
```

Comment: what do you mean by associative hash array? could you explain a bit more? I guess it's a data structure type, how would one implement it?

Comment: It will keep the keys in unique way. if you push the text content in hash array key, it will ignore the duplicate key while pushing in that array. Finally you will have the unique text. Refer http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_hashes.html

Comment: "Associative hash array" - in ruby we just call it a "hash" :)

Comment: 'it will ignore the last "TextContent2"' - no, it will not. Quite the opposite, in fact.